# Game theoretical approach to other branches of mathematics

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, game-theory

Are there some methods and ideas derived from game theory that are successfully applied to better (or more intuitively) understand theorems and proofs or tackling problems from other areas of mathematics (for example, number theory, calculus, algebra, probability, ...)?

If there are, can you (1) list them (2) suggest books or papers that describe such methods?

Comment: [Conway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway)'s work could interest you for example his [Hackenbush game](http://books.google.com/books?id=0--3rcO7dMYC&pg=PA284) and his numerous explorations in the [Winning ways](http://www.amazon.com/Winning-Ways-Your-Mathematical-Plays/dp/1568811306) books with Berlekamp and Guy.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome Dal!

Comment: If *combinatorial game theory* is on agenda, then see e.g.[Impartial achievement and avoidance games for generating finite groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0784) by Dana C. Ernst and Nandor Sieben. Its bibliography contains more references, e.g. to [Algebraic games](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2884) by Martin Brandenburg.

Comment: Game theory is important in descriptive set theory. In particular Choquet games and Banach-Mazur games are applied. Try Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory. Dynamic games are used in optimal control.

Comment: @Student Can you provide some references?

Comment: Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory

Comment: http://www.springer.com/economics/economic+theory/book/978-0-387-25804-1

Comment: http://books.google.be/books?id=EEay92bVDFgC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=dynamic+games+in+control+theory&source=bl&ots=WIDHm4Y7bJ&sig=Eqem1egDIMznMw28guFzwhk6oGY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dBBJVNqzOuu9ygPbyIKYAQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=dynamic%20games%20in%20control%20theory&f=false